# Electra "Hello World!"

Tags: code-golf, tips, hello-world

This will be a bit of a different challenge. Back in 2023, I developed a 2D esolang called Electra, and looking back at my hello world program, (which is 582 bytes by the way) I see a lot of room for golfing. There are some topics that aren't covered in the spec, e.g. in which order the currents are generated/interpreted, but I'll consider an answer correct if it works on the main implementation. Anyway, the challenge is: Write a program that prints "Hello World!" with a newline character at the end, to stdout in Electra, using the least amount of bytes possible. I am eager to see your clever submissions! Here's a [link](https://github.com/DolphyWind/Electra-Lang) to the interpreter, the README.md file contains the spec. Use of dynamic components and including other files is disallowed.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! IMO this would work better as a [deadlineless bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadline), so I have voted to close this

Comment: I think this question could make a good [tag:tips] question. To fit [our standards for a "help me golf this code" question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18610/on-golf-this-for-me-tips-questions), you will need to golf your Hello World code as much as you can and include it in the question. Answers will then attempt to golf your code further and explain how they did it.

Comment: @DLosc has brought to my attention that you don't have the rep for a bounty, I'll offer 50-100 of my own rep should you decide to make this a bounty instead

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've closed this as a duplicate of our standard Hello, World! challenge, as we maintain that as a repository of all answers that output `Hello, World!`. As other users have mentioned, you are welcome to offer a bounty (deadline-less or not) once you have the reputation to do so (although Seggan has also offered some of their reputation towards this), to encourage people to do this; additionally, reframing this as a [tips] question as already suggested would qualify this answer for reopening, though this has a couple of prerequesite changes as linked by DLosc.

Comment: I could make this a bounty, as @Seggan suggested when I find the time to golf it myself